# How to map a pointer pointer to a structure by JNA?

Tags: jna

Now I have defined a c structure as following:

```
struct HostNameEntry {
    char *hostName;
    struct HostNameEntry *next;
};
```

And I have defined a method as following:

listHosts(HostNameEntry **hostNameListPtr)

The above method will retun a HostNameEntry back the caller.

How to mapping this structure/method by JNA? And how to get the hostName stored in HostNameEntry?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You tag a version of your HostNameEntry class with Structure.ByReference to force the field to take on a pointer value (instead of being inlined).

```
public class HostNameEntry extends Structure {
   public static class ByReference extends HostNameEntry implements Structure.ByReference { }

   public String hostName;
   public HostNameEntry.ByReference next;

   public HostNameEntry() { }
   public HostNameEntry(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
}

public interface MyInterface extends Library {
    MyInterface INSTANCE = ...;
    void listHosts(PointerByReference pr);
}

// actual usage
PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
MyInterface.INSTANCE.listHosts(pref);
HostNameEntry first = new HostNameEntry(pref.getValue());
```